# Should I be concerned about rust on a post in my basement?

Tags: repair, concrete, walls, basement

How long do support posts last? Any reason to be concerned with rust on them? Seem to be working fine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Obviously rust isn't a good thing. I don't seen enough here for immediate concern, but eventually you'll need to replace them if action isn't taken.

Since they appear to be sitting on the slab, as opposed to being embedded in it, you can easily replace them with screw-type floor jacks. They aren't terribly expensive, and you could use a bottle jack and a wood 4x4 as a temporary post while you do the work.

You might just paint these, though. Use a wire brush to clean away loose material, then apply a suitable primer. Stop there or add a nice top coat. Wait 20 years and repeat.

Comment: Thanks! You have responded to a handful of my questions so much appreciated. Very informative for first time homeowner and not savvy with this stuff. Safe to say my support system at the house is safe for now based on your comments. These beams seem to last a long time

Comment: Posts. Beams go sideways. :)

Comment: Indeed they do...

Comment: Those posts can outlast many generations with almost no maintenance but as isherwood said it would be a good idea to wire brush and prime it.+

Answer (score 0):

Some structural steel is designed to allow the outer surface to rust, because it then forms an oxide layer that prevents the more destructive deep rust.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weathering_steel

Comment: True, but what's your advice in this specific case?